# How to include Listener type class in the WPF/MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Imagine you have Listener class that will connect on app start to some server with Connect method, then it starts to listen to messages and on every received message it raises event OnRecievedMessage. Based on these messages you need to update viewmodels which in turn update views. What's more you have to run Listen() method on new thread in order to don't block UI, so event OnRecievedMessage will also run on this new thread.

How would you incorporate such class in structure of WPF/MVVM application and how to connect it with viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario I would not use an event - I would expose `IObservable<T>`
Because the IObservable will be an object and can be easily passed and returned to/from a function you gain:

- easily inject this into your Viewmodel
- filter/map and dispatch to the UI-Thread
- unhook the handlers easier (Dispose vs. "-=")

So don't pass your "Listener" class around - pass the IObservable you implement/expose there around!

Make sure to have a look at the [Rx-Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)

Comment: thx, i will look at that framework, but for now what if i have to use event, because it is only way that class can respond to recieved message and i have no access to code to alter its behavior

Comment: you can wrap the event into a IObservable ... so np. if you cannot change the Listener - just create a wrapper

Comment: so listener should be wrapped in iobservable class and viewmodel should implement iobserver? In this way it makes me sense.

Comment: yes you could do this - or you could make an IObservable-Property in your Listener and/or take the IObservable as an argument to your Viewmodels constructor (injecting the interface) - this way the Viewmodel must not implement IObserver.

Comment: thank you very much i understand it now, this is leading to successfull incorporation